# I can't seem to install command rake db:create db:migrate db:seed on windows 7. I get this warning ! Can anyone help me? I

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 rake db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Currently, Active Record suppresses errors raised within `after_rollback`/`after_commit` callbacks and only print them to the logs. In the next version, these errors will no longer be suppressed. Instead, the errors will propagate normally just like in other Active Record callbacks.
>
> You can opt into the new behavior and remove this warning by setting:
>
> ```
> config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
> ```

Comment: It's not an error It's just a deprecation warning

Comment: i am share full full warning @deepak

Answer (score 0):

In my Rails config/application.rb file I had put

ActiveRecord::Base.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

right below

require 'rails/all'

to prevent that warning.